# How do I read a text file on my local disk into a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am trying to read in a .json file from my local machine. it will not read it in the code I am using is:

```
jQuery.getJSON('../json/test.json') 
    .done(function(data) {
        var test = data;
        alert("sucsess");
    })
    .fail(function(data){
    alert("failed");

});
```

All I am getting from this is failed what am I doing wrong. I am not going through a server with this.

Comment: If your webserver is not on your local machine, this will not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the File APIs. Here's a guide with sample code and demos:

- [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score 8):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDNFX/1/)

```
<title>reading Text files</title> 
<body>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>
    <script>
      function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Print the contents of the file
                var span = document.createElement('span');                    
                span.innerHTML = ['<p>',e.target.result,'</p>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the file
        //reader.readAsDataText(f,UTF-8);
        //reader.readAsDataURL(f);

        reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry but if you run the page from local drive ( address bar will have the form file:///path to your page) then you may read a file from disk, but if your run a script from webserver (http://......) you cannot read file from local drive. It's protect you from stealing information from user drive. You may need to upload a file in order to read it

EDIT: I have to take it back. New browser will allow you to read file based on user event. If user click file input and open a file then you can read it

Answer (score 2):

You can't acess files on your local machine via JavaScript due to security reasons etc....

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to
>   deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser
>   authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run
>   in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not
>   general-purpose programming tasks like creating files.

But I've found this website but never gave that a try, maybe helps you:
[Reading local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

**Edit:** If you are never gonna run your code on a webserver and only execute it on your local system(calling index.html in browser like: C:/Users/user/index.html you could access it, but if this website should ever gonna go online, which I suppose, that's not going to work

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about file on local (client) system and not server, than that's not possible with simple javascript. You can't access local file system resources.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.getJSON call is asynchronous, so you can see your test variable only inside function(data){...}