# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know this question has been asked many times , I have gone through all solutions but could not solve the issue.

I am new to programming and want to make a page that load some content in a div with id "content" through java script.

This is my index page

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">home</a>
  <a href="#">about</a> 
  <div id="content">
   <script src="loader.js"></script>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my loader.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('home.html');
});
```

when I run index.html i get

> jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/my_folder/home.html.

all the files are in same folder named my_folder.

Comment: In Jquery latest version `.load()` method has been deprecated.  https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: @Samir: Wrong method. The .load to load something into a tag is not deprecated. It is the https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ that is deprecated, not https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @mplungjan, in the reference which i mention, there it is mention `.load()` method has been deprecated right? `.on("load")`, is the replacement of that. Please tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Samir yes it is the  on("load") shortcut .load - the "load-event" that has be deprecated - the OP is looking at .load("file") not .load("function")

Comment: @mplungjan the link you gave me is not related to my issue, actually the scenerio of my website is that i have another page home.html which i want to load in content div.

Comment: The page I gave is answering your actual question I believe. Please see [what-is-the-xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you are NOT trying to load the page from your own harddisk then [how-do-i-read-a-text-file-on-my-local-disk-into-a-variable-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046919/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-on-my-local-disk-into-a-variable-in-javascript) is not the valid duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer of my question

i have changed my script to

```
    function load_home(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
return false;
}
```

and call this function in content div

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately XMLHttpRequest can not be called to local resources, EVEN IF the HTML ist stored locally.

Its because you can programatically read the contents of local files and send them into the web, what is not allowed.