# Jquery read txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I have a text file which is located in a particular folder nn the server.  The folder location is stored in the web.config.

I am able to get the value of the folder location in jquery but I am able to read the txt file:

Below is my code:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
var fileName = baseUrl + "/" + fileLocation.split("/").pop() + "/" + evt.currentTarget.id;
jQuery.get(fileName, function (data) {
            $("#pdfviewerJs").html(data.replace('n', ''));
        });
```

The evt.currentTarget.id is the name of the file and the pdfviewerJs is just a div to display content of text file.
Somehow this is not working.
The fileName is as below:

> http://localhost:58003//D://ViewerTest//test_1240560034094.txt

Any help pls..?
I just need to get the file and display the content of the txt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file on my local disk into a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046919/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-on-my-local-disk-into-a-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: @Diar selimi the question clearly says the file is located on the server

Comment: Tabby you need to provide a URL to the file, not a disk path. The browser cannot see the server's filesystem

Comment: What do you mean by "Somehow this is not working"? What happens instead? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: @ADyson:  But then I really can't read the txt file using javascript?

Comment: I don't quite get your point. The file is on your server, so to use .load() you need to provide a valid URL to it. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Where are you getting the value of `fileLocation` from right now, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson: fileLocations is from the web.config

Comment: Right so the value in the web.config needs to be a URL (or part of a URL, if you're going to put baseURL in front of it). A web page cannot access a file by its disk path, it **must** be a valid URL

Comment: @ADyson: Ok I understand.  If the folder was under the deployment folder then I can easily access it.  Else no.  Right?

Comment: That's right. Although of course if you are using IIS you can configure it to serve other folders as well